# DNS issue causing NoMethodError: undefined method `fb_error_code'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, sidekiq, opendns, googledns

We were using OpenDNS instead of GoogleDNS on our Digital Ocean Server. Looks like some outrage in the DNS in Google and OpenDNS is causing the following time out erros

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `fb_error_code' for #<Faraday::ConnectionFailed>
```

I have changed the following configuration

```
# /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 208.67.222.222 
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

and

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
```

and rebooted the system. But The sidekiq which used to normally take 1-2 min is not taking over 20mins to complete and throwing a lot of errors.